# Javascript find objects that contain matching elements from arrays in another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, underscore.js

I have two objects:

```
const people = [
{
    name: "Dave",
    fruit: ["apple", "pear"],
    veg: ["asparagus", "peas"]
},
{
    name: "Frank",
    fruit: ["mango", "banana"],
    veg: ["sweetcorn"]
},
{
    name: "Alice",
    fruit: ["mango", "peach"],
    veg: ["asparagus"]
}];

const demographics = {
  fruit: ["apple", "mango"],
  veg: ["asparagus"]
}
```

I would like to find which 'people' like the fruit 'apple' or 'mango' and the veg 'asparagus', as defined in the 'demographics' object, like so:

```
[{
    name: "Dave",
    fruit: ["apple", "pear"],
    veg: ["asparagus", "peas"]
},
{
    name: "Alice",
    fruit: ["mango", "peach"],
    veg: ["asparagus"]
}]
```

I've been staring at this all day and am not advanced enough to dig into objects like this. Can anyone help? If possible, I would like to use underscore, but not essential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first I converted the demographics object to an array so i can iterate easily. after that filter the person array with the conditions
check every demographic where in each demographic at least 1 satisfies (is inside the veg or fruit.. arrays of a person).
You can find equivalent methods `pairs`,`filter`,`some`,`every`,`contains` if you want to convert above using underscore

```js
const people = [
{
    name: "Dave",
    fruit: ["apple", "pear"],
    veg: ["asparagus", "peas"]
},
{
    name: "Frank",
    fruit: ["mango", "banana"],
    veg: ["sweetcorn"]
},
{
    name: "Alice",
    fruit: ["mango", "peach"],
    veg: ["asparagus"]
}];

const demographics = {
  fruit: ["apple", "mango"],
  veg: ["asparagus"]
}

const demographicsEntries = Object.entries(demographics)

const res = people.filter(person => demographicsEntries.every(([k,v]) => v.some(val => person[k].includes(val))))

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

people in here is an array of objects.

```js
const people = [
{
    name: "Dave",
    fruit: ["apple", "pear"],
    veg: ["asparagus", "peas"]
},
{
    name: "Frank",
    fruit: ["mango", "banana"],
    veg: ["sweetcorn"]
},
{
    name: "Alice",
    fruit: ["mango", "peach"],
    veg: ["asparagus"]
}];

const demographics = {
  fruit: ["apple", "mango"],
  veg: ["asparagus"]
};

people.filter(person =>
    person.fruit.some(fruitName=> demographics.fruit.includes(fruitName)) && person.veg.some(vegName=> demographics.veg.includes(vegName)) && person);
```

Hope this will help (y)

Answer (score 0):

Modern JavaScript has a lot of really useful array and object methods that you can use to spare the additional code footprint of Underscore.

In essence (links to documentation below) you want to `filter` out all of the people who have at least `some` of the elements in their fruit/veg arrays that appear in `every` corresponding query array.

```js
const data=[{name:'Dave',fruit:['apple','pear'],veg:['asparagus','peas']},{name:'Frank',fruit:['mango','banana'],veg:['sweetcorn']},{name:'Alice',fruit:['mango','peach'],veg:['asparagus']}];

// Accepts some data, and the query object
function find(data, query) {
  
  // `filter` out all the people...
  return data.filter(person => {
    
    // ...who, for every query key (fruit/vegetable),
    // have at least one item in their fruit/veg array
    // that includes an item in the corresponding query array
    return Object.keys(query).every(key => {
      return query[key].some(el => {
        return person[key].includes(el);
      });
    });
  });
}

const query={fruit:['apple','mango'],veg:['asparagus']};
console.log(find(data, query));

const query2={fruit:['apple'],veg:['peas']};
console.log(find(data, query2));

const query3={fruit:['banana'],veg:['peas']};
console.log(find(data, query3));
```

Additional documentation

- [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)
- [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)
- [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
- [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/keys)